# How can I authenticate my SOAP request using OAuth Access Token in Salesforce?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I have the typical soap verification using username and password.

```
SoapClient loginClient = new SoapClient("Soap");
string username = "<myemail>";
string password = "<mypassword>";
string token = "<mytoken>";
loginClient = new SoapClient();            
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
LoginResult lr = loginClient.login(null, username, string.Concat(password, token));
endpoint = new EndpointAddress(lr.serverUrl);
sessionHeader = new SessionHeader
{
      sessionId = lr.sessionId
};
client = new SoapClient("Soap", endpoint);
```

I have created a Rest API connection using connected apps that brings back an TOKEN VALUE using OAUTH 2.0
How can i use that token to Authenticate my Soap calls instead of username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value of the oauth token in the `sessionId` field instead of the one you get from login()